# Использование autofac в asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, autofac

Здравствуйте. 
Может кто-нибудь дать адекватный пример на использование ioc autofac в [asp.net](http://asp.net) mvc? Нужно чтобы создавался контроллер, в который в качестве параметра конструктора передаются экземпляры классов, имплементированных от интерфейсов (т.е. вполне обычная задача), но в конструктор у самих этих классов нужно передать connectionString, и в этом у меня проблема.

Comment: Чем не подходят примеры кода с сайта-производителя?

Comment: Видимо тем, что у меня не получается заставить их работать, иначе бы я не писал сюда. Там есть пример для mvc3, но в нем нет работы с web.config . Если есть, но я не вижу, тыкните пальцем, пожалуйста. Сейчас максимум, чего я добился - вручную регистрировать типы в Global.asax, регистрируя еще и контроллер с указанием, что подавать в конструктор типа builder.Register(c => new MyController(c.Resolve<IMyRepository>()... И при этом выскакивает, разумеется исключение, что IMyRepository нужен connectionString, а его нет. Да и не вариант это - для каждого из кучи контроллеров руками прописывать.

Answer (score 1):

[Пример](http://habrahabr.ru/post/136895/)

Регистрировать контроллеры руками не нужно - реализуйте IDependencyResolver для своего ИоКа.

Comment: Вам наверно кажется просто все очевидным и Вы даже не берете в расчет, что можно так тупить, как я:).
Смотрите.
В Global.asax я пишу
var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
            builder.RegisterModule(new ConfigurationSettingsReader("autofac"));
            builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes();
            builder.RegisterControllers(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
            var container = builder.Build();
            DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new AutofacDependencyResolver(container));

Comment: Конфигурационник имеет вид:
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="MSSQL" connectionString="Server=.;Database=MyBase;Trusted_Connection=yes;"/>
  </connectionStrings>
  
  <autofac>
    <components>
      <component service="DataAccessLayer.Abstract.IMyRepository, DataAccessLayer" type="DataAccessLayer.Concrete.SqlMyRepository, DataAccessLayer">

      </component>
...
</autofac>

Теперь вылетает исключение, что в контроллере нет конструктора без параметров. Т.е. все-таки что-то неверно, и он не хочет подставлять экземпляры нужных классов в конструктор.
P.S. Спасибо Вам за помощь.

Comment: Мне не кажется это все очевидным и ваши вопросы вполне адекватны. Более того, я никогда не работал с автофаком - предпочитаю продукты "кастла". Попробуйте в дебаге посмотреть граф зарегистрированных типов внутри контейнера и убедиться, что нужные классы таки были зареганы (последовательность добавления иногда тоже важна). Данный еррор мне кажется говорит о том, что какие-то типы не были успешно зарегистрированы. (Кстате говоря, конекшен стринг можно один раз вытащить руками в глобал-асаксе и сетить более привычным образом остальным типам при регистрации, если ну никак не получается иначе...

Comment: Какая-то странная ерунда. Все типы там как раз зарегистрировались как нужно, в том числе и контроллеры. Нужно, видимо, дальше гуглить... По крайней мере можно уже более точно формулировать вопрос.

Comment: Попробуйте что то вида: builder.RegisterType<Type>().As<IType>().WithParameter("parameter_name",parameter).InstancePerRequest();